# Why is Joomla based website that was copied off of live server into localhost not showing pictures and throwing 404 error?

Tags: htaccess, joomla, 404, xampp, localhost

I have copied Joomla based website via FTP onto my machine and I am trying to make it run on my localhost which is provided by the latest version of XAMPP. I have exported and imported the DB with no problems. I have placed all the files and folders into HTDOCS folder but when I go to localhost example site all I get is the text that is on the front page but no pictures and it displays 404 Error. Do I need to make changes to .htaccess? If so, can some one point me to the right direction? Thanks

Comment: What is the URL for the image coming out as? And what should it be?

Answer (score 1):

This being not a discussion forum, i'll just answer the question.

We cannot be sure that .htaccess has anything to do with the issue you are experiencing, because a 404 error can also depends on other factors. The better thing you can do is to rename it from ".htaccess" to "htaccess.txt", so that it gets disabled, and check again if your site works.

My guess is that, unless you previously made significant changes to this file, it is not the cause of the issue.

So, on a bonus note:
 - check carefully configuration.php file and verify *_path and live_site parameters
 - if you are able to access the administrator part of the site, disable all Joomla or 3rd party SEF functionalities.

If this does not lead you to a functional site there is some serious misconfiguration and a simple answer surely can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration error. It depends on the type of website software you are using. Sometimes these can take a long time to debug. 
I would also advise installing the Xampp on another machine. 
   Open the browser to the url. Scroll down to the end of the page and get the error message. Copy that into Google with the brand. "Error loading show_html.php Joomla" 
You will probably find a dozen possible fixes. Also google "Error loading show_html.php Joomla Xammp"

Make sure the user, login and permissions (in database) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar happen before, and in that case, it was because of how the links on the images/urls/everything were set up. In this case, on a test.website.com, all the urls were written in such a way that they weren't portable. For example the navigation links were setup like:
    About
Because of this, they retained the 'test' part when the site was made live. Instead, they should have been written like:
    About
So that no matter what the url of the site was/is/will_be, the navigation to "About" will not be broken. This happened to ALL the links and images on the site and was a huge mess.

I apologize about the anecdote, but perhaps this is what is happening with you? The case I saw it happen with was Wordpress when it was moved off the test to the live server... all the links had to be manually changed in order to point to the right places.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Akeeba backup component. it Backups your site as it is and you can install it in any other server by running the kickstart installer provided in the same webpage as component.